# How do I control teleport control?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

I found a ring of teleport control, which I've heard is a very useful thing. Unfortunately, when I then read a scroll of teleportation, I didn't teleport anywhere, even after a few turns. How exactly do I control the teleport?

Comment: This question breaks my brain.

Comment: Did the TELE status appear?

Comment: @SaintWacko Don't know. I've died since. I didn't think to look for it.

Comment: If you had any unidentified jewelry equipped, it's possible you were wearing something with Stasis, which would have prevented the teleport.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally when you teleport while wearing a ring of teleport control, when the teleport activates a few turns later, it gives you a box similar to the e<kbd>x</kbd>amine box, which allows you to choose where you'll land. However, I checked your morgue file, and the thin bone amulet you were wearing was an unidentified Amulet of Stasis. If you had been watching your message log when you read the teleport scroll, you would have seen the message:

> You feel a sense of stasis.

The Stasis effect prevents teleportation from any source, and thus caused your teleport to fail.

Comment: I do remember reading that message, but I had no idea what it meant. This answer is kind of creepy, but kind of awesome.